# Compactification of sine curve

Tags: general-topology

The title may be a little inaccurate because part of my issue is that I can't make complete sense of what the following question is asking, let alone how to go about solving it:

> Note that if $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded continuous injection, then the closure of $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ if $\gamma((a,b))$ is open in $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Find $\gamma$ as above, such that the function sin$\circ\gamma^{-1}:\gamma(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a continuous extension to $Y = \overline{(\gamma(\mathbb{R}))}.$

So I'm hoping someone might be able to explain the problem a bit more clearly and help me get started toward a solution.

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Since $\gamma$ must be an injection, then $\gamma^{-1}$ is a function from $\gamma(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma^{-1}(\gamma(\mathbb{R})) = \mathbb{R}$. So, perhaps naively, it seems equivalent to write sin$:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and sin$\circ\gamma^{-1} : \gamma(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then if that's the case, I don't get what it means to extend sin$\circ\gamma^{-1}$, since it is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, $\gamma(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $\overline{\gamma(\mathbb{R})}$, so you can ask to extend the function $\sin\circ\gamma^{-1}$ to $\overline{\gamma(\mathbb{R})}$.

Comment: Right, thank you. Beyond that elementary confusion, I'm afraid I'm still lost as far as finding such a $\gamma$.